# Removing objects from NHibernate second level cache 

Tags: nhibernate, caching, second-level-cache, isession

I just started thinking about using the NHibernate second level cache in one of my apps. I would probably use the `NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider` which relies on ASP.net cache.

Enabling the cache was not a problem, but I am wondering on how to manage the cache e. g. programmatically removing certain entities from the cache etc.

My application is some kind of image database. The user uploads images over a backend and can view it in the frontend by accessing `/ImageDb/Show?userId=someUserId`

The data does not change very often. And if it changes, the users would not matter a button named "clear my cache" in the backend that removes the cached objects for *this user* from the cache.

I found a solution online that can remove *all* cached objects from nhibernates second level cache. But thats a bit too brute force for me ... I dont want to clear the whole cache for dozens of users just because one user tried to clear the cache for his own data.

So what I basically wanted to do: selectively remove cached db objects from nhibernates second level cache in C#.

Is this possible? I guess it also depends on the cache provider. If this is not doable with the ASP.net cache provider, I am open for other built in / open source suggestions.

Comment: I know it's probably not relevant now but note that your URI scheme is incorrect. It should be Users/[Id]/ImageDB/Show

Comment: @the_drow - unless the app is called ImageDb :) You're still mostly right, just have to change ImageDB to /Images or something

Comment: @LukeSchafer: I wrote ImageDb only because the OP uses it.

Comment: @the_drow - yeah, sure, was just pointing out it might be a virtual directory is all :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

the sessionFactory provides the methods you want...
from the [19.3 chapter of the NHibernate reference](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-sessioncache):

To completely evict all objects from the session cache, call ISession.Clear()
For the second-level cache, there are methods defined on ISessionFactory for evicting the cached state of an
instance, entire class, collection instance or entire collection role.

```
sessionFactory.Evict(typeof(Cat), catId); //evict a particular Cat
sessionFactory.Evict(typeof(Cat)); //evict all Cats
sessionFactory.EvictCollection("Eg.Cat.Kittens", catId); //evict a particular collection of kittens
sessionFactory.EvictCollection("Eg.Cat.Kittens"); //evict all kitten collections
```

Comment: The role name here in the first parameter is the full Namespace+Classname+Propertyname of what you need to evict.  You can see everything in cache by calling sessionFactory.GetAllCollectionMetaData().Keys.